# Unserialize() is Not Working

Tags: php, serialization

I have a PHP script (referred to as client) that is getting a request from a PHP script (referred to as server) on another server. The server serializes this data and sends it to the client:

```
stdClass Object (
    [version] => 0.3
    [date] => 2010-04-10
    [package] => http://my.site/test-plugin-update/test-plugin-update.zip
    [slug] => test-plugin-update
    [new_version] => 0.3
)
```

The client takes it and unserializes it like this: `$response = unserialize($raw_response['body'])`

But, `$response` is empty!

If I do this: `var_dump(unserialize($raw_response['body']))` I get this: `bool(false)`

If I do this: `print_r($raw_response['body'])` I get this:

```
O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:7:"version";s:3:"0.3";s:4:"date";s:10:"2010-04-10";s:7:"package";s:56:"http://my.site/test-plugin-update/test-plugin-update.zip";s:4:"slug";s:18:"test-plugin-update";s:11:"new_version";s:3:"0.3";}
```

If I manually paste that inside of an `unserialize()` call, I get a beautiful object like this:

```
stdClass Object (
    [version] => 0.3
    [date] => 2010-04-10
    [package] => http://my.site/test-plugin-update/test-plugin-update.zip
    [slug] => test-plugin-update
    [new_version] => 0.3
)
```

Any idea why I'm getting this kind of behavior, or what I can do to unserialize the string programmatically?

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump(serialize($raw_response['body']))`?

Comment: @melpomene Here's what I get—a serialized string inside of a serialized string: `s:217:" O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:7:"version";s:3:"0.3";s:4:"date";s:10:"2010-04-10";s:7:"package";s:56:"http://my.site/test-plugin-update/test-plugin-update.zip";s:4:"slug";s:18:"test-plugin-update";s:11:"new_version";s:3:"0.3";}";`

Answer (score 0):

I asked you to run

```
var_dump(serialize($raw_response['body']));
```

You got the output

```
s:217:" O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:7:"version";s:3:"0.3";s:4:"date";s:10:"2010-04-10";s:7:"pack‌​age";s:56:"http://my.site/test-plugin-update/test-plugin-update.zip";s:4:"slug";s‌​:18:"test-plugin-update";s:11:"new_version";s:3:"0.3";}";
```

As you can see in the beginning (`s:217:" 0:8`...), you have a space before the actual `serialize` output starts. When I try to `unserialize` that, I get this notice: `unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 217 bytes` (offset 0 because `unserialize` doesn't expect a space at the beginning).

The correct fix is to figure out why your server is adding a space before sending the serialized output and fix that.

But as a workaround you could probably do

```
var_dump(unserialize(preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $raw_response['body'])));
```

on the client.